# MAUI interaction between the `BlazorWebView` component and the other components of the MainPage

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

I have a MAUI app strongly based on Blazor `BlazorWebView`.

The main page is simple: a `Grid` with a `BlazorWebView` and an `ActivityIndicator`.

Is it possible to have some form of interaction between the `BlazorWebView` component and the other components (in my case, but not only, with the `ActivityIndicator`)?.

Maybe by using MainPage events or something else (?)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Quiz.Blazor.Maui.Standalone"
             x:Class="Quiz.Blazor.Maui.Standalone.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">
    <Grid>

        <BlazorWebView
            x:Name="myBlazor"
            HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
            <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Main}" />
            </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        </BlazorWebView>

        <ActivityIndicator
            x:Name="myActivityIndicator"
            Background="transparent"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            HeightRequest="60"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="60"
            Color="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}"
            IsRunning="False"
            IsVisible="true" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

For example, when in Blazor there is a long operation, I'd like to set the `ActivityIndicator.IsRunning` to `true`.

### Update 1

At the end of the story the Blazor content when is in a `BlazorWebView` seems to not working as when it runs into a web browser in terms of rendering during long operation.

Here it is my brazor component that perfectly works when it runs into a browser:

```html
    <h1>Take your quiz!</h1>

    @if (WaitingCnt > 0) {
        <div class="spinner" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
    }

    the rest of the html code here...
```

and the code behind

```cs
        protected async Task PrepareExamSessionSubmittedHandler(PrepareExamSessionRequestDto input) {
            WaitingCnt++; // <= show the spinner!
            //StateHasChanged();  // useless :-(
            try {
                // time expensive op...
                ...
            } finally {
                if (WaitingCnt > 0) WaitingCnt--;  // <= hide the spinner
                //StateHasChanged();  // useless :-(
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to use .Net MAUI controls in Blazor(.razor file)? You can try to set static property ActivityIndicator , then call it using Application.Current.MainPage.

Comment: My final goal it to show a spinner for the long operations. I updates my questions to better explain it By the way I'm really interested in know how "to set a static property ActivityIndicator and call it using Application.Current.MainPage"

Comment: For use .Net MAUI controls in Blazor, this issue can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74015992/how-to-use-net-maui-controls-in-a-net-blazor-maui-app#:~:text=TL%3BDR%20You%20can%20get%20access%20to%20some%20native%20dialog%20controls%20from%20the%20Application%20class%20provided%20out%20of%20the%20box.

Answer (score 2):

On the internet you can find [documentation and posts about how to interop between JavaScript and .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet) but the pitfall of most of those is that they relate to interop **within the Blazor domain**. The confusing thing about those documents is that they discuss JavaScript and .NET as if they are generic things, but they really do not point out the limitations of interop across the boundaries of the Blazor / non-Blazor contexts.

To my knowledge, it is not possible to directly call methods on the Blazor (Razor) components from the Native side of the app, and calling methods on the Native side from the Web side is limited.

In .NET MAUI with Blazor, the Blazor (Web) part and Native (XAML) part run in the same process. This results in these things you **can** do:

- Call MAUI platform functions from Blazor .NET (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/build-blazor-hybrid/9-exercise-platform-features)
- Use dependency injection to inject shared state objects (singletons) in your Blazor code and your native code. Set and get data from the state object from Blazor or the Native code. An example of this approach is https://stackoverflow.com/a/72780073/1114918
- Use dependency injection to inject services in your Blazor code. Call methods on the service from Blazor like you already know in the Native code.
- Use events to pass data across the Native / Blazor boundary. These can be .NET events like @gonzalorf in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019291/1114918, but I found a cleaner way using `WeakReferenceMessenger` from the MVVM Community Toolkit. This is demonstrated in e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-podcasts/blob/main/src/Mobile/Blazor/ListenTogetherComponent.razor.

Long story short, using [`WeakReferenceMessenger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger) you can post messages across the Native / Blazor boundary and this way you can e.g. communicate between your MAUI ViewModel (used in XAML) and your Razor component.

The code below shows **how to let code on the Native side (ViewModel) make requests to the Blazor side (Razor component)** using an `(Async)RequestMessage<T>`. The other way around is also possible, and it is also possible to publish values (using `ValueChangedMessage`) instead of requesting them.

## Code sample

Define a `(Async)RequestMessage<T>`

```cs
public class GetSomeDataFromBlazorRequestMessage: AsyncRequestMessage<SomeDataFromBlazor> { }
```

In Razor, register to listen for request messages, for example in the component's `OnInitialized()`:

```cs
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<SomeBlazorComponent,GetSomeDataFromBlazorRequestMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
    {
        m.Reply(r.GetDataInsideBlazorAsync()); // We're replying with a Task<SomeDataFromBlazor>. This is the async way, non-async is also possible.
    });
}
```

In your ViewModel in MAUI, request the data from Blazor via the WeakReferenceMessenger using

```cs
SomeDataFromBlazor result = await WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send<GetSomeDataFromBlazorRequestMessage>();
```